# first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a GUI app using PyQt5 and Python 3.7 and I've decided to break the code in different modules. When i try to import a function that creates an instance of a custom widget, an error related to 'sis'. What I read is that 'sis' is a way of encapsulation C/C++ code to be run in python. But how can I work with that?
This is the code that runs the app:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(10,35,1500,800)
        self.setWindowTitle("Cotizador TuCheff")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(''))
        mainWindow(self)


    def mainWindow(self):
        from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
        from Pages.Quote import quote


        barMenu = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)

        tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        quoteLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        quoteGenerator = quote.makeQuoteWindow()
        quoteLayout.addWidget(quoteGenerator)
        tab1.setLayout(quoteLayout)

        barMenu.addTab(tab1, "&Nueva Cotización")


        self.setCentralWidget(barMenu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And file, where I try to get a custom widget, is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys



def makeQuoteWindow():
    quoteWindow = QuoteWindow
    quoteWindow.create()
    #app = QApplication([])
    #window = quoteWindow()
    #window.show()
    #status = app.exec_()
    #sys.exit(status)


class QuoteWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QuoteWindow, self).__init__()

        def create(self):

            mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            vLayout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()



            #=======------------------------ UPPER SIDE -------------------

            hLayout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()


            ##A LOT OF WIDGETS AND LAYOUTS

            hLayout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()


            #display content
            vLayout1.addLayout(hLayout1)
            vLayout1.addLayout(hLayout2)
            hLayout2.addItem(vSpacer1)
            mainWidget.setLayout(vLayout1)

            return mainWidget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    makeQuoteWindow()
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: create(self, window: sip.voidptr = 0, initializeWindow: bool = True, destroyOldWindow: bool = True): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: 1) change `quoteWindow = QuoteWindow` to `quoteWindow = QuoteWindow()` 2) add `return quoteWindow` after `quoteWindow.create()`

Comment: @eyllanesc Great answer as always. Poor job of a moderator, who linked urelated question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

#        from Pages.Quote import quote
from Quote import QuoteWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(10,35,1500,800)
        self.setWindowTitle("Cotizador TuCheff")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))

#        mainWindow(self)
        self.mainWindow()

    def mainWindow(self):
#        from Pages.Quote import quote
        self.quoteWindow = QuoteWindow()             # +++

        barMenu = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)

        tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        quoteLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

#        quoteGenerator = quote.makeQuoteWindow()
#        quoteLayout.addWidget(quoteGenerator)
        quoteLayout.addWidget(self.quoteWindow)       # +++

        tab1.setLayout(quoteLayout)
        barMenu.addTab(tab1, "&Nueva Cotización")
        self.setCentralWidget(barMenu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

**Quote.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class QuoteWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QuoteWindow, self).__init__()

    def create(self):
        mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        vLayout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        #=======------------------------ UPPER SIDE -------------------
        hLayout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        ##A LOT OF WIDGETS AND LAYOUTS
        hLayout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        #display content
        vLayout1.addLayout(hLayout1)
        vLayout1.addLayout(hLayout2)
        hLayout2.addItem(vSpacer1)
        mainWidget.setLayout(vLayout1)

        return mainWidget
```

[image]

Comment: TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'